# Javascript syntactic sugar for classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

As it says in every tutorial about OOP about javascript "Classes are just synctactic sugar introduced in ES6 and actually classes it's simply functions", but nobody show how it turns into function and because of that i have a question: How my Example class in code below would look after it turns into function and where it's properties and functions will be allocated and accessed later?

```
class Example {
   constructor(a, b) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
   }

   changeA() {
      this.a = 5;
   }

   changeB(b) {
      this.b = b;
   }
} 

// Suggested allocating instance here, but what allocates and how it looks "behind the scenes"?
let ex = new Example(1, 2);
```

Comment: go to https://babeljs.io/repl and put your es6 code there and see the transpiled version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class syntax allows you to quickly create instances of a prototype.  In your example, `Example` is a prototype, and `ex` is an instance of that prototype.  While `1` and `2` are specific to the `ex` instance of `Example`, the `changeA` and `changeB` methods belong to the *prototype* of `ex`, which is `Example`.  If you `console.log(ex)`, you won't see `changeA` and `changeB`, you'll only see `a: 5, b: 2`.  But you'll also see a `__proto__` property.  Click that open in the console and you'll see your methods there.  So any instance of `Example` will have those methods.

I recommend learning more about prototypes and inheritance in javascript.  Learn and understand these *first*, then understanding why `class` is syntactic sugar will be easier.